# Forbid contributors viewing drafts

Tags: privileges

Is there any way I can forbid a contributor to view draft posts? Right now any contributor can view my draft posts and even edit them (however their edits must be approved by administrator first).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you might need a plugin like '[User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)'. You can then edit the capabilities of roles, including contributors.

So they can edit their own posts/drafts, but not the posts/drafts of others you should ensure that core capabilities:

- `edit_posts` is checked.
- `edit_others_posts` is unchecked